# RPi0 simply hangs after a few weeks

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have an RPi0 set up in my crawl space to measure and record Temp/Humidity over time. Simply put, a Python program runs using Chron every few minutes, collects the temp/humidity and sends them to a cloud-based database ("one and one") using a simple HTTP page that runs a simple PHP program to add a line to the MySQL database table. No feedback (at least none on purpose...) The db is updated as expected for several weeks (long enough for me to be lulled into a false sense of security....) Then it stops. The RPi0 cannot be reached with SSH.

I unplug it, bring it up to my office, plug it in and it starts working again, no problem...No disk full symptoms (total usage 19%.) Spurious python messages show up, but they just talk about type conversion warnings.

Rinse and repeat.

Ignore the INSERT setup for the local database. I've commented out the actual command execution because I no longer use the local db.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import MySQLdb
import time
import urllib2

from Adafruit_BME280 import *

# BMP working, DHT not so much

sensor = BME280(address=0x76,t_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, p_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, h_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8)

# conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.204",user="jim",passwd="xxxx",db="EnviroLogger")
# c=conn.cursor()
humidity=0
temperaturec=0
# humidity, temperaturec = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
temperaturef=((temperaturec*9.000)/5.000)+32.000

datatime=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())

dhtvalues="(null,'DHT-8200-Crawl',"+str(temperaturef)+","+str(humidity)+",null,'"+datatime+"')"


time.sleep(1)
BMPtemperaturef = ((sensor.read_temperature()*9.000)/5.000)+32.000
hectopascals = sensor.read_pressure()/100.0000
BMPhumidity = sensor.read_humidity()

bmpvalues="(null,'BMP-8200-Crawl',"+str(BMPtemperaturef)+","+str(BMPhumidity)+","+str(hectopascals)+",'"+datatime+"');"

finalSQLstring="INSERT INTO ResDataLog(ID,Location,Temperature, Humidity, Pressure, RecDate) VALUES " + dhtvalues +","+bmpvalues
# c.execute (finalSQLstring)
# conn.commit()

#Get Weather info from DarkSky

from forecastiopy import *

MyLatLong=[34.985928,-80.767389]
DarkSkyKey='587336fab8f4f5e8766aee23ca5cfee79f390943221acedddwerreffafde'

fio=ForecastIO.ForecastIO(DarkSkyKey, latitude=MyLatLong[0], longitude=MyLatLong[1])
current = FIOCurrently.FIOCurrently(fio)
ambienttemp=current.temperature
ambienthumidity=current.humidity
ambientpressure=current.pressure

url="http://telemetry.mywebhost.com/add_data.php?loc="+"BMP-8200-Crawl"+"&temp="+str(BMPtemperaturef)+"&hum="+str(BMPhumidity)+"&pr="+str(hectopascals)+"&atemp="+str(ambienttemp)+"&ahum="+str(ambienthumidity)+"&apress="+str(ambientpressure)
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

How can I somehow capture what happens here and save it somewhere just before it dies?

Comment: This behavior is not related to your script. Just schedule maintenance reboot once a week or a day. Most likely it is related to WiFi - so it is probably alive but lost connectivity. Next time have serial connection ready to check whether it is alive or not. If it is WiFi connection issue then you could write simple watchdog script to reset "stale" connection. Also here is a community related to RPI devices: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ . Most likely they have answer to your issue.

Comment: Maxim, I think that's a good guess. I've had trouble with certain devices being unable to reconnect after rebooting the client, solved only by rebooting the router. I'm not sure how to write that script. I'll google it. Thanks again, Maxim.

Comment: Also, the RPi community is not particularly robust, but I will try there next time.